# How to mock databases access while testing urls with Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to test some django application urls. However, the associated views are linked to the database. What I'd like to do is mocking these aspects of the view method, but I have no idea how.

Let's suppose I want to try the `/signin` url, whici is a classical signin form.
The associated view looks like this :

```
def login(request):
    if 'user' in request.session:
        return redirect(reverse("home"))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            return treat_login(request, username, password) # checks if couple 
                                                              is present in 
                                                              database, returns 
                                                              pages accordingly
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form, })
```

In my test, I have no implicit call to the `login` method, since I only use the `url` :

```
class Tests_urls(TestCase):
    def test_signin(self):
        self.client.post(reverse("login"), {"username":"login", "password":"pwd"})
        self.assert_http_status(url, status, "after a standard login")
```

The problem with that test is that it needs a database to be performed, wich is what I  want to avoid (I can't use use the embedded test database).

As a consequence, I would like to know how to mock the `treat_login` method from the test point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use patch from the [mock libarary](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)

```
from mock import patch

class Tests_urls(TestCase):
    @patch('my_app.views.treat_login')
    def test_signin(self, mock_treat_login):
        self.client.post(reverse("login"), {"username":"login", "password":"pwd"})
        self.assert_http_status(url, status, "after a standard login")
        self.assertTrue(mock_treat_login.called)
```

You can also inspect the call args. But the way you have written this test makes that a bit hard. If you used the [request factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.client.RequestFactory) and tested the function by doing something like

```
request = self.factory.post(
    reverse("login"), {"username":"login", "password":"pwd"})

response = login(request

mock_treat_login.assert_called_once_with(request, "login", "pwd)
```

Then you could actually make sure you were calling it correctly.